# Unity - atoms - how do I get two atoms to stick to each other and move as one GameObject?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am making a chemistry game in Unity where each atom is represented as a 3D GameObject sphere.  I want the user to be able to drag an atom around and if it enters some set radius of another item that it can combine with, the two atoms "stick" together (or become "suctioned" together) and become one entity that can be dragged around and interacted with.

How it looks now:

[image]

How I want it to look after interaction:

[image]

Now comes the hard part trying to figure out how to do this.  First, I attached a script to the Oxygen atom (red sphere).  I want to see if the Hydrogen atom entered some radius.  If it does, I create a new GameObject, make both the oxygen and hydrogen children of that object, give the new GameObject a rigidbody and collider, and turn off the rigidbodies of the children. So the problem with this is that once I do that, both spheres fall through the ground.  Also, they still remain as separate spheres and don't look "stuck" together.  If I drag the red sphere around, the white doesn't follow and vice versa.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if(collision.gameObject.name == "HydrogenPrefab(Clone)")
    {
        Debug.Log("Hydrogen entered");
        GameObject HOCombo = new GameObject();

        //put both atoms under the same parent
        collision.gameObject.transform.parent = HOCombo.transform;
        this.transform.parent = HOCombo.transform;

        //remove the rigidbodies
        this.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = true;
        collision.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = true;

        // make the parent a rigidbody;
        HOCombo.AddComponent<Rigidbody>();
        HOCombo.AddComponent<MeshCollider>();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you're going to want to look into a [Fixed Joint](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-FixedJoint.html) approach - sounds like exactly what you need.

Comment: Making the rigidbodies kinematic is not the same as removing them.

Another problem would be the mesh collider you add. If you check the GameObject in the editor, you will probably notice that it lacks a mesh.

@Serlite is correct though, a joint would be best.

Comment: This is quite simple but did you think about the next step? And the step after? I assume you want to make larger and more complex molecules at the end of the day. Possibly not giants like macromolecules but skeletal or chicken wire ones maybe. Do you have a plan how to do all these? As that's your pattern/model you should define and apply to the easy/simple structures too like water. Just an advice...

Comment: Hi again! `Fixed Joint` approach looks very promising. The reason you could only drag the red atom is that when you do `raycast` to get the sphere, it only returns the very first collider it hits. And because you didn't disable collider on children there is a very high probability that your `raycast` hits it (it could hit parent collider as well but I guess you are not lucky enough). When it hits, you get the child, not the parent => you drag the child, not the parent => expected behavior. :3

Comment: Thanks for the `FixedJoint` suggestion.  I managed to get two atoms to stick together and that works great.  However, for a molecule like water, I need two hydrogens to stick to oxygen and I haven't found out how to get two fixed joints on a single object.  Also, if someone can write an answer to this question, I'll accept it.

Comment: @noblerare And you are slowly arriving to the thing I described above and asked you about above...

Comment: @Mark - right, I see what you mean so I'm trying to figure out if FixedJoints can be applied in multiples or if there's some other way (e.g. HingeJoints) that can allow me to do what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a [Fixed Joint](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-FixedJoint.html) could suits you. 
Also make sure that you get the right object when you Raycast it. You'll probably need to move the children to a layer ignored by your raycast or use [RaycastAll](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.RaycastAll.html) to get all hits (not just the first one) and manage to find the desired parent from there.

Comment: `Fixed Joints` is correct but I also wanted to add that in order to get multiple of them, I had to attach the Fixed Joints to the child objects and make them children to a parent.  In my case, I added FixedJoint components to the hydrogen objects and made the hydrogen objects children of the oxygen object.